# How to query array inside nested object using mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have complex object stored in my mongodb look like this:

```
     const collectionFromMongodb = [
      {
        id: ObjectID(),
        text: 'blabla',
        data: {
          foo: [
            { id: ObjectID(), status: 'ready' },
            { id: ObjectID(), status: 'notready' },
          ],
          bar: [
            { id: ObjectID(), status: 'ready' },
            { id: ObjectID(), status: 'notready' },
          ],
        },
      },
    ];
```

I want to query the all the object (`find`) but the object that return will have in `foo` and `bar` only object that `status` are `ready`. (`data.foo.[?].status === 'ready' and/or data.bar.[?].status === 'ready'`).

I expect to get all the object (since my filter is only on `data`), but the fields of foo and bar contains only the `status` of 'ready'.

Note: In `foo` and `bar` I have data size of 1mb.

How to do that with mongoose query? is it possible to do? or just query all object and use `filter` and `map`?

I did this but not works, because its gets all the statuses in `data.foo`:

`find('data.foo': { $elemMatch: { status: 'ready' })`

Comment: in your question `table` is not an object, it looks like an array of objects.

Comment: table mean to collection. sorry

Comment: Your condition `and/or` is not possible. Is has to be either one of them? You need to satisfy both condition or either one of them?

Comment: do you mind posting an expected result?

Comment: Hmmm... in the end I need the object with `foo` and `bar` (if any) only those with status of `ready`.

Comment: How about combining them with `$or` ?

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is what you need. Change the $match pipeline to whatever u need to find.

https://mongoplayground.net/p/o1qk4wla5C6

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "data.bar.status": "ready"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "data.foo": {
        $filter: {
          input: "$data.foo",
          as: "foo",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$foo.status",
              "ready"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "data.bar": {
        $filter: {
          input: "$data.bar",
          as: "bar",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$bar.status",
              "ready"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: can I do it with find only please?